# Escape character for $ in Bash file

Tags: bash

I need to create a bash file to rename files,where I need to have filename with **$** symbol.

Eg:- **Na$me**

how can I escape this **$** symbol, **/** is not working to escape **$** symbol

Comment: Did you mean \?  / isn't backslash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to deactivate `$` in shell:

1. You can use single-quotes:

   ```
   $ var='Na$me'; echo "$var"
   Na$me
   ```
2. You can use a backslash:

   ```
   $ var=Na\$me; echo "$var"
   Na$me
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answers,Both methods are working fine